# Heroku push rejected, the path to rails engine does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fullcalendar

When attempting to deploy my rails app on heroku, 

`git push heroku master`

I get the following error:

`` remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        The path `/tmp/fullcalendar-rails-engine` does not exist.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        The path `/tmp/fullcalendar-rails-engine` does not exist.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app ``

The path is referencing a rails engine (https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine) which is included in my Gemfile. However I don't ever reference a tmp folder in '/tmp/fullcalendar-rails-engine'.

I'm not sure how to address this issue. Just to see if I could deploy my app, I tried removing the gem from the Gemfile and commented out the mounting in my app but even when trying to push the deploy after that, I still received the same error.

Comment: Did you run `heroku create` first?

Comment: @hiveer yes I did :)

Comment: out of interest when you removed the gem did you bundle install?

Comment: @Emma yes I did but thanks for the reminder because after I read your comment, I realized I didn't commit my changes! Thereafter I was able to deploy the app but would still like to include the rails engine...

Comment: ah glad to head this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a dirty fix, but I added the indicated folder to the tmp folder of the project. Still curious about why this happened and if making that actually solved anything.